# Displaying data via table format (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 columns of data in my database in Android application. I want to display this data via a **table format** in my application. Please help me.

For example, I have `employeename` and `department` coulmns in the database. I want to retrieve this data and show it in a table format like a table with 2 columns. One side `employeename` and next column their respective `department` in my Android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want user interact with the table, you can use webview and make it load table html. Advantage of this method is that you can make it as fancy as you want.

If you want interaction with the table, you'd better use listview with customized row layout, or even gridview would work too.

Comment: @NishaWilson If you used my answer, please upvote and accept my answer by clicking up mark and check mark. That's how this site works.

Comment: i have marked it ....since im new to this,i dint actually know that i had to do so....anyways thanks..!